# Minimal jQuery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a UI, in which user can add / delete items (of similar layout).

It starts with one item and you can click 'add' to add more. The UI consists of several different types of items.

What I am doing currently is populating a single item `item 1` ( of each type ) and on `add` event, I clone the `item 1`, replace the changes done by user in `item 1` and append the clone to the `container`. 
In simple words, instead of dynamically creating html with jQuery, I am cloning html of a `div`. But in this approach , I had to change a lot of things to keep to give the new item to initial state.

So, I want to avoid the replacing the edits done by user, so I was thinking something like below,

```
<script type="text/template" id="item_type1">
  <div>
    <div>Box</div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="item_type2">
  <div>
    <div>Box2</div>
  </div>
</script>
```

And on `add` event, I want to do something like `$('#item_type1').html()` and `$('#item_type2')` to create new items.

I know there are sophisticated libraries like handlebar and mustache and underscore has its own way of implementing templates.

But I am not using any of these already and thus do not want to included them just to copy content.  I dont want anything special. I am not passing variables. I am just cloning some markup to use again and again.

Is this way to insert `html` in `script` tags , going to work in all browsers ? and is it a good way  ?

**EDIT:**

Its for the wp plugin and I assume js is turned on , else the plugin wont work anyways.

Comment: They're not sophisticated they're libraries, just try them. At least you'll go straight designing your templates instead of writing your own engine!

Comment: I just want to copy some html. Why would I use a library for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

Your HTML should be, for example:

```
<script type="text/template" id="item_type1">
  <div>
    <h1>Box1</h1>
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
</script>
```

And your code would be:

```
var templateHtml = $('#item_type1').html();

var $item = $(templateHtml);
$('body').append($item);
$item.on('click', function() {});
```

This is an easy way that will work on all browsers.

Comment: I do not want to pass some arguments.

Comment: Sorry, fixed ... no arguments to pass!

Comment: You didnt read my question. I know I can do this. I've mentioned the same in question. I am asking will it work across browsers  ? (if you have used it earlier) or do you have a better way. Also, why are you doing `$(tempalteHtml)` ? its totally redundant

Comment: Yes, it will work, including IE6+. But I think you're question is not that clear!

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Create an HTML file with your template inside of it
- Step 2: Using jQuery's `load()` method, call your HTML template into a `div` element in the main HTML file:

  `$("#main-div").load("yourtemplate.html")`
- Step 3: Be amazed

**Is this a good idea? *It depends:***

If it's a self contained application on a known environment with a determined supported browser and with equally determined settings (like if JavaScript is on or not) then yea, sure. Why not?

If it's open to the public in every single browser possible with many different configurations, then no, it's a horrible idea. If your user doesn't have JavaScript enabled, then your content doesn't show up. Also, if one of your scripts break in production, then you are again left with no content. You can learn this lesson from when [Gawker made this same mistake](http://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2011/02/07/gawker-outage-causing-twitter-stir/)